# Why does $\operatorname{Log}(e^{3+4i})=3+(4-2\pi)i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I believe I am more used to the concept in the Real Numbers, but I am not sure why the answer here includes $-2\pi$. I'm assuming it has something to do with where $z=3+4i$ falls in the complex plane? Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to find two distinct complex numbers $z_1,z_2$ such that $e^{z_1}=e^{z_2}$? What relation is there between $z_1$ and $z_2$?

Comment: @Arthur, what comes to mind is that e^z1= e^x1(cos(y1)+isin(y1))=e^x2(cos(y2)+isin(y2))=e^z2 and thus y1 and y2 would be some multiple of 2pi from each other. Is that along the right track?

Comment: Very much so. If you take a closer look, you will see that that's exactly what has happened in your equality.

Comment: So that makes sense, but I'm still a little hung up over why it is -2pi as opposed to 2pik where k is in the integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex logarithm $\operatorname{Log}$ is a *function*. Which means for any given input, it can only give a single output. However, each non-zero complex number has infinitely many logarithms. So to make a function we need to make some kind of choice. One standard choice is to always give an output with imaginary part in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$.

*One* logarithm of $e^{3+4i}$ is obviously $3+4i$. However, it has a slightly too large imaginary part for our taste. So we move down one step to $3+(4-2\pi)i$ to get a logarithm in the right range. That's how $\operatorname{Log}$ works.

Comment: [$(-\pi,\,\pi]$, actually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition).

Comment: @J.G. Fair enough. I think I've seen both, but there is no harm in aligning with Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be:

$3+4i=3(4-2\pi)i$

$3+4i=3+4i-2\pi i$

$0\neq -2\pi i$